# How to know if SSL established at HAProxy level on app level?

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I have an HAProxy instance that is available from the web, and redirects incoming requests to my local app.

The communication between the client and my HAProxy can be secured via SSL but not necessarily, and I need to know at my application level if the communication is secure or not.

Unfortunately, from my understanding, the communication I get in my app is already "decrypted" from all the SSL communications, HAProxy handling the "SSL wrapping".

Is there a way to know for sure that the client is using SSL/TLS or no?

**Update** The communication is not HTTP but TCP at HAProxy.

Comment: I don't think so. Why? Because TLS is endpoint to endpoint. Only the proxy would know. So...make it mandatory for all clients.

Comment: That's what I suspected. As an example to represent the issue, it would be the same as having :80 and :443 point to the web app. The web app need to know if the channel is encrypted or not. My best solution so far is to test the current port used: `isSecure = port === 443`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the purpose of the [X-Forwarded-Proto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto).
You can make HAProxy insert that header if ssl traffic was decrypted by HAProxy:
`http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }`

Then your application will just have to check the X-Forwarded-Proto.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know the type of communication was important, but I'm not using HTTP, I'm using TCP, so a header is not possible, unfortunately.

Comment: IMO, there is no way the application behind the proxy can get information about the request/connection between the client and HAProxy (or any other proxy) unless the proxy inserts that in the traffic to the backend application.  
So in your case since you cannot insert headers (TCP mode), the only solution would be to use the [PROXY](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt) protocol. But for that to work you need to check if your application supports PROXY protocol

Comment: That's what I ended up doing yes. By using the PROXY protocol, I get the original PORT too, so I check the connection (443 for instance) to guess if it's SSL or not.

Comment: HAProxy sends information about the original ssl context via `PP2_TYPE_SSL` type, in case your application parses it.

Comment: Do you have an example of the communication between HAProxy and a TCP service to see how and when this data is sent? Thanks.